# How to upload my emails to another email server I've downloaded via IMAP from my 1st one?

Tags: email, synchronization, imap

I want to download my emails via IMAP from email account and upload them to another. I want to **do that manually in Python**. I know how to retrieve my emails via IMAP, but how can I actually "upload" them to my another email account? Is there a standard way or does that depend on my 2nd email server?

Comment: Is this just an exercise, and if not, why do you want to use python and not `imapsync`?

Comment: @Law29, because.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload with python as well:

```
import imaplib

# an alternative for IMAP4_SSL is IMAP4 if you're doing this locally
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(your_2nd_server, its_imap_portnumber)  
imap.login(user_name, password)
```

and then for each message you downloaded:

```
imap.append(mailbox, [], delivery_time, message)
```

You have to get the delivery time out of the message header for this.

Comment: does imap allow me to upload an email? is that by specification?

Comment: @OskarK. Sure it is [APPEND](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#section-6.3.11), that is how you can e.g. move an email from one (IMAP) account in Firefox to another.

Comment: @OskarK. do note that "uploading" an email only means that you put it in the box, not that you send it to anyone, for that it's (still) SMTP.

Comment: @Law29 That is in principle correct, although there are extensions for IMAP so you don't have to use SMTP **and** upload the same email to your send-items box if your IMAP server and SMTP server are on the same (remote) machine.

Comment: @Anthon is that an extension to IMAP itself or is it "only" an agreement between the server and client that whatever the client puts in its outbox will be treated as a mail to be sent?

Comment: @Law29 The IETF LEMONADE Working Group has made some RFCs for that (4467-4468-4469) I don't know of any servers actually implementing them.

Comment: what does "in the box" mean?

Comment: @OskarK. If you don't add `@law29` to your comment (s)he will not be notified. `box` is short for `mailbox` (on your IMAP server)

Comment: I only need to put my emails into a box via IMAP, don't I?

Comment: @OskarK.  Yes the code I presented is what you need. Just ignore the exchange between Law29 and me, that is about IMAP + SMTP inefficiencies and doesn't apply to your situation.